# Can't remove margin beneath iframe

Tags: html, css

I've created a codepen for this, but the issue is basically beneath my YouTube embed there's a margin (Seperating the footer from the page) and I don't understand why, I'm still learning when it comes to web development, so I'll be grateful for any explanations.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyjaVJ

```
Links to codepen must be accompanied by code, 
but it's all on codepen, considering there's not much.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because an `iframe` element is `inline` by default. The reason you are seeing whitespace below the `iframe` is because `inline` elements are aligned this way so that there is reserved space below the element for letters such as p, y, q.

You could either change the `display` of the `iframe` element to `block`: [**(example)**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYGjpb)

```
iframe {
  display: block;
}
```

..or you could change the value of the `vertical-align` property to something other than the default value of `baseline`. In this case, a value of `top` would work: [**(example)**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jExMBW)

```
iframe {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can still use what you have, if you edit your CSS and change this code:

```
#body_wrapper footer {
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

Not exactly a professional way to do things as you will see the comments i shall get for it but it does fix your problem at hand.

Comment: with most websites going into a responsive design, you never know if it's going to be 6 or 80 pixels.

Comment: ..also, the amount of whitespace will vary depending on the `font-size`. Hardcoding a negative margin is unreliable.

Comment: As i saw that this website that is being created was not responsive as of yet, i decided to help with an unprofessional and lazy way of fixing the problem.